# javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.171

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, scenebuilder

compile-single:
run-single:
févr. 22, 2020 12:20:23 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.171
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 12 seconds)
****I got this error even though I just updated my java to the latest version...****

Comment: a) that's a warning, not an error. b) you dont seem to be using the new version of java to run the app. Have you checked the jre's directory is listed in a place in the path variable where it takes precedence over the older version or you"ve changed the settings in your IDE or you've associated the correct jre with the jar ending, depending on how you launch the program?

Comment: You version mentioned in the fxml file mismatches the java version the program is run with.